# android keyboard does not appear

Tags: android, motorola

So I've an edittext that I try to get the keyboard for if it's in focus when tilted.

I'm working with a device from motorola, MC40. Android version 2.3.4.

I check if it's in focus, I've debugged and seen that it's in focus. I've tried the following:

```
txtQuantity.selectAll();
txtQuantity.requestFocus();
```

Thou while that works in other parts of my program, it does not work in this activity.

The edittext is focused on, but the text is not selected and the keyboard is not there.
The edittext is a bit down on the screen, on other activities it's a bit higher up. I believe that's why the keyboard does not show, correct or wrong?

If I force the keyboard with

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Then the keyboard it shown. However, for some strange reason, my edittext box now shrinks to 1/3d of it's former size and you can't see what's written in it!

This issue is starting to get to me.

**Edit**:

This event seems to help, as a work around. However, I get a popup asking me to chose between 3 choises, words/all/inmethod. If I choose the middle one, it works, but I need to do that programmatically some how.

```
edittext.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
```

**The edittextbox**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/..."
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/..."
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/..."
    android:layout_below="@+id/..."
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/..."
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/..."
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/..."
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
```

Comment: Try posting the layout xml. It may end up helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

and then in your manifest file you can put the following in the `<activity>` tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: I have this in my manifest: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"

Comment: Why `stateHidden` might I ask?

Comment: The code base is in part inherited, not sure. I did change to only adjustpan, but no different. The edittext get's cut in half when forcing it with    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

Comment: How about just removing `stateHidden` and keep the other two?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that method unfortunately you are using as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that worked for me. I had a similar issue, where I would requestFocus on my EditText but the keyboard would not show.

```
public static void showKeyboardForEditText(Context context, EditText editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Here is the code if you need to close the keyboard:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, EditText editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: its a long shot but maybe check that android:focusable="true" is set in the edittext xml in your layout?